# How to convert CGPoint to SCNVector3

Tags: swift, scenekit

How to convert CGPoint to SCNVector3?

I want to transfer the touchpoints in UIView to the SceneView. But how?

I couldn't find any resources in the forum.

Answer (score 2):

Just look at your `SCNView` class, there is a lot of juicy stuff in there.

```
/*!
@method hitTest:options:
@abstract Returns an array of SCNHitTestResult for each node that contains a specified point.
@param point A point in the coordinate system of the receiver.
@param options Optional parameters (see the "Hit test options" group for the available options).
*/
let hitResults:[SCNHitTestResult] = mySCNView.hitTest(point, options:[:])
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnhittestresult

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnhittestresult/1523058-worldcoordinates